# Stream video from WP 8.1 to TV via DLNA

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I am working on the Windows Phone 8.1 app, in which I want to implement online video streaming and **play video from windows phone device to TV through DLNA via wifi** connectivity.

similar functionality to LUMIA PlayTo app, but want to stream online video over TV through DLNA.

can any one help with this because has googled a lot, but haven't found anything relevant
Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: This might be an interesting read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playto.aspx (it states it's supported for WP8.1, not sure about how to handle the stream though)

Comment: This thing doesn't work for me. It is not supported in WP8.1

Answer (score 2):

That is a fairly broad question. There is a MediaElement control you can use to play video. Maybe the open source PlayerFramework is more helpful. It provides a way to play lots of content, including progressive downloads, streaming, live streaming, protected content, advertisements, etceteras. And you can style the player as you see fit.

Have a look at http://playerframework.codeplex.com for the downloads, sources and documentation.

An easy start can be found here: [Getting Started Guide](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%3A%20WP8%20Smooth%20Streaming%20Player&referringTitle=Windows%20Phone%208%20Player%20Documentation).

***Attribution for answer***

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32179633/5252270)

[Author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4768214/martin-tirion)

Answer (score 1):

Use and study this 
[Sample code](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/)