# Windows Mobile TV stream

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-phone

I want to develop an application to play live stream on Windows mobile devices. Please **give** me an example of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a fairly broad question. There is a MediaElement control you can use to play video. Maybe the open source PlayerFramework is more helpful. It provides a way to play lots of content, including progressive downloads, streaming, live streaming, protected content, advertisements, etceteras. And you can style the player as you see fit.

Have a look at http://playerframework.codeplex.com for the downloads, sources and documentation.

An easy start can be found here: [Getting Started Guide](http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%3A%20WP8%20Smooth%20Streaming%20Player&referringTitle=Windows%20Phone%208%20Player%20Documentation).